# Playwright page.click scrolls too much

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, playwright

Given I want to record the action being done the page, when clicking on an element
Playwright scrolls the page until the element is on top of the page, even though before the action the element is visible in the viewport.

P.S. the option "scroll: false" does nothing

code snippet:

```
await Promise.all([
    global.page.waitForNavigation(),
    global.page.click(global.identifier, { scroll: false })
]);
```

L.E.:
I want to add some more details about my issue using an example:

So, let's assume I want to do a click action on the "Answer your question" button, and page looks like this:
[image]

after the click is performed the page automatically scrolls, putting the button on top of the page, like this:
[image]

My expectation is, if the element is in viewpoint, just to perform the action, without scrolling or moving the viewpoint.

Comment: There is no `scroll` option in Playwright

Comment: See here for all available parameters which the. `page.click` function supports https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click. If you experience any issues with it, I would recommend to create an issue in their GitHub repository to get official support here.

Comment: thanks a lot, guys, for your answers, I've just added some more details about my issue, in case you encountered some similar issue, and you have any sugestion.

Answer (score -2):

I also faced this issue so I resolve this by doing **scroll into the view function** [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
await page.$eval(ele, (element) => {
    element.scrollIntoView();
});
```

So here's the full code

```
const playwright = require('playwright');
const moment = require('moment');
(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--disable-notifications']
  });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127885/playwright-page-click-scrolls-too-much');
  await page.waitForSelector('.js-accept-cookies')
  .then(() => page.click('.js-accept-cookies') );
  let ele = '#submit-button';
  await page.$eval(ele, (element) => {
      element.scrollIntoView();
  });
  await page.click(ele);
  let date = moment();
  await page.screenshot({ path: `example-scroll-${date}.png` });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Attaching screenshot for reference:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

It will resolves your issue

await page.$eval(`div#whatsapp.whatsapp-correlation`,(ele)=>{
ele.scrollIntoView();
});